# Jetty 9.x ProxyServlet - how to set up ServletContext correctly in XML

Tags: xml, configuration, reverse-proxy, jetty-9

Aiming to start Jetty locally with a webapp servlet and a proxy servlet both running, and other tools like deploy and console logging.  All Jetty configuration is in XML files.

The proxy servlet will reverse-proxy `GET` requests prefixed `/media/*` to an external site `https://example-server/`.   So http://localhost:8080/media/image.jpg will pass through to https://media-server/image.jpg.

Here's an extract from my `jetty.xml`:

```
<Set name="handler">
  <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
    <Set name="handlers">
     <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
       <Item>
         <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
       </Item>
       <Item>
         <New id="context" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
           <Arg><Get class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler" name="SESSIONS"/></Arg>
           <Call name="setContextPath" arg="/"/>
           <Set name="servletHandler">
             <New id="handler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
               <Call id="holder" name="addServletWithMapping" arg="org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet$Transparent,/media/*">
                 <Call name="setInitParameter" arg="proxyTo,https://media-server"/>
                 <Call name="setInitParameter" arg="prefix,/media"/>
               </Call>
             </New>
           </Set>
         </New>
       </Item>
       <Item>
         <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
       </Item>
     </Array>
    </Set>
  </New>
</Set>
```

The above XML should be equivalent to this Java code.

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
ServletHolder holder = handler.addServletWithMapping(ProxyServlet$Transparent.class, "/media/*");
holder.setInitParameter("proxyTo", "https://media-server");
holder.setInitParameter("prefix", "/media");
context.setServletHandler(handler);
```

That is adapted from the default `jetty.xml` and https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-jetty-servlet-proxy

From the DZone guide I've updated the class names for Jetty 9.x.  So `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ProxyServlet` is now `org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet` and the `proxyTo` and `prefix` parameters must start with a lowercase `p`.

Checked that `jetty-proxy-9.4.12.v20180830.jar` is included as a library in Jetty's startup configuration.

For logging, the Jetty command line includes `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.proxy.LEVEL=DEBUG` (I recommend this for anyone else troubleshooting ProxyServlet.)

**The problem:** nothing's happening.  The `ProxyServlet` is not activating on `GET` requests to `http://localhost:8080/media/image.jpg'.

Here's the log line showing the `ServletContextHandler` is starting.

```
2018-09-28 15:26:46.045:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e028a9{"",null,AVAILABLE}
```

I guess there's simple solution to this, like setting the ServletContext correctly, but I can't figure out how to do that in XML, and would really appreciate some help.  Jetty [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) on this is thin.

Now if I change the `jetty.xml` to this below then the proxy **does** activate on `GET` requests to `http://localhost:8080/media/image.jpg'.

```
<Set name="handler">
  <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
    <Set name="handlers">
     <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
       <Item>
         <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
       </Item>
       <Item>
         <New id="handler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
           <Call id="holder" name="addServletWithMapping" arg="org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet$Transparent,/media/*">
             <Call name="setInitParameter" arg="proxyTo,https://media-server"/>
             <Call name="setInitParameter" arg="prefix,/media"/>
           </Call>
         </New>
       </Item>
       <Item>
         <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
       </Item>
     </Array>
    </Set>
  </New>
</Set>
```

The log shows the ProxyServlet activating like this:

```
2018-09-28 14:22:14.904:DBUG:oejpP.194a1b5:qtp22374712-13: org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet$Transparent-194a1b5 @ null/media to https://media-server
2018-09-28 14:22:14.904:DBUG:oejpP.194a1b5:qtp22374712-13: 21964987 rewriting: http://localhost:8080/media/image.jpg -> null
```

But here the proxy fails because it has a `null` context.    So the prefix has been set ([source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AbstractProxyServlet.java#L720-L726)) to `null/media` is because the `ServletContext.getContextPath()` is null. And that causes a  redirect to `null` because of [this source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AbstractProxyServlet.java#L729-L733).  With `_prefix` set to `null/media`, nothing's going to match that.  Possibly that's a bug, I've opened an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using a `ProxyServlet` from a `${jetty.base}` directory.

```
$ mkdir proxy-example-base
$ cd proxy-example-base/
$ java -jar ../../jetty-home-9.4.12.v20180830/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy,proxy
INFO  : webapp          transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=webapp
INFO  : server          transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=server
INFO  : proxy           initialized in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO  : security        transitively enabled
INFO  : servlet         transitively enabled
INFO  : http            initialized in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO  : client          transitively enabled
INFO  : threadpool      transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=threadpool
INFO  : deploy          initialized in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
MKDIR : ${jetty.base}/webapps
INFO  : Base directory was modified
$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   4 joakim  staff   136 Oct  1 14:10 ./
drwxr-xr-x  17 joakim  staff   578 Oct  1 14:10 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 joakim  staff  2146 Oct  1 14:10 start.ini
drwxr-xr-x   3 joakim  staff   102 Oct  1 14:11 webapps/
$ cp ~/Downloads/media-proxy.xml webapps/
$ cat webapps/media-proxy.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Call name="addServlet">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet$Transparent.class</Arg>
    <Arg>/media/*</Arg>
    <Set name="InitOrder">1</Set>
    <Call name="setInitParameter">
      <Arg>proxyTo</Arg>
      <Arg>https://media-server/</Arg>
    </Call>
    <Call name="setInitParameter">
      <Arg>prefix</Arg>
      <Arg>/media</Arg>
    </Call>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

The way this works is that `${jetty.base}` is configured to have the `proxy` jetty module enabled, which puts the proxy classes on the server classpath.

Then the `deploy` jetty module is enabled to find configurations of webapps in the `${jetty.base}/webapps/` directory and deploy them.

Finally, an XML deployable is setup to have a `javax.servlet.ServletContext`, at the `/` contextPath, and one defined servlet, the `ProxyServlet$Transparent` with some init-parameters.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.  This XML seems equivalent to the following Java code: `ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
ServletHolder = context.addServlet(ProxyServlet$Transparent.class, "/media/*");
holder.setInitOrder(1);
holder.setInitParameter("proxyTo", "https://media-server");
holder.setInitParameter("prefix", "/media");`

Answer (score 1):

One workaround solution - not exactly what I wanted to do, but it works - is to launch the ProxyServlet from the `web.xml` associated with the webapp.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>JettyProxy</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet$Transparent</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>proxyTo</param-name>
    <param-value>https://media-server</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/media</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JettyProxy</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/media/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Additional gotchas:**

- Any filters defined in your `web.xml` also now need the `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` line
- Your project now requires the `jetty-proxy` library jar as a dependency (version must match your Jetty version), like this:

  ```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-proxy</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

There are a few differences between doing it this way from the `web.xml` and doing it from Jetty's own configuration as I wanted to do in the OP.

1. the proxied URLs must now be in this form (where webapp is the webapp name): http://localhost:8080/webapp/media/image.jpg
2. the webapp must update `web.xml` when the Jetty version changes - could be a problem for remotely hosted apps
3. each webapp must include this, instead of it being "built in" to Jetty
4. it feels inelegant compared with setting up different servlets for different paths as Jetty is capable of - is there a performance hit here, because the proxied URLs are now also being parsed by the webapp's filters?
5. possible blocking of the webapp's threads while the proxy request cycle completes (needs testing...)